# How to pass a string containing both single and double quotes as a parameter to XSLT in PHP?

Tags: php, xslt, string, escaping, quotes

I have a simple PHP-based XSLT trasform code that looks like that:

```
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl->registerPHPFunctions();
$xsl->setParameter("","searchterms", $searchterms);
$xsl->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);
```

The code passes the variable $searchterms, which contains a string, as a parameter to the XSLT style sheet which in turns uses it as a text:

```
<title>search feed for <xsl:value-of select="$searchterms"/></title>
```

This works fine until you try to pass a string with mixes in it, say:

```
$searchterms = '"some"'." text's quotes are mixed."
```

In that point the XSLT processor screams:

> Cannot create XPath expression (string
>   contains both quote and double-quotes)

What is the correct way to safely pass arbitrary strings as input to XSLT? Note that these strings will be used as a text value in the resulting XML and not as an XPATH paramater.

Thanks,
Boaz

Comment: addslashes may be it will work for u.. before adding it in..

Answer (score 1):

This has been logged as a bug:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64137

This comment:

> This shortcoming comes from the fact that XPath 1.0 does not provide a mechanism to escape characters, so PHP does not have a straightforward way to express a string that contains both types of quotes. XPath 1.0 does, however, provide a function to concatenate strings. Using concat(), a string composed of the two characters "' can be expressed as concat('"',"'"). concat() takes 2 or more arguments.

Includes the following work-around:

> So as long as you alternate the quoting style, you can express a string containing any number of quotes of both types.

Another solution is to replace all straight-quotes with single-quotes:

```
$t = str_replace( "\"", "''", $t );
$xsltEngine->setParameter( "some-text", $t );
```

Answer (score 0):

if your final output is HTML you could try htmlencoding it. As long as entities are set in stylesheet should be OK

Answer (score 0):

You could use `&apos;` to escape the single quotes:

```
$searchterms = '"some" text&apos;s quotes are mixed.'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to replace the single quotation marks with html special characters using `str_replace`

```
$t = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $t);  
$xsltEngine->setParameter( "some-text", $t );
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in one of the answers, this is a bug. Therefore, you can not pass both quotes.

But you can replace the double quote with another character, and then use `translate` to restore the original.

The main thing to choose is a character that will not appear on your text. For example `\x7F`.

```
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl->registerPHPFunctions();
$xsl->setParameter("","searchterms", strtr($searchterms, '"', "\x7F"));
$xsl->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);
```

and

```
<title>search feed for <xsl:value-of select="translate($searchterms, '&#x7F;', '&quot;')"/></title>
```

Also, you can not use html entities, since they are being escaped.

Or use `disable-output-escaping="yes"`:

```
<title>search feed for <xsl:value-of select="$searchterms" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></title>
```

with

```
$xsl->setParameter("","searchterms", htmlspecialchars($searchterms));
```

The first method you can use for built-in expressions. For example:

```
<title attr="foo {translate($searchterms, '&#x7F;', '&quot;')} bar">bazz</title>
```